# Would a process with the higest nice value use only *free* CPU time

Tags: linux-kernel, nice

I want to be sure that a scheduled job, mostly using gzip, will not impact the production.
This is an old **Linux** server with few CPU, it has SAN attachment so the gzip is running at its maximum using 99% of a processor.
I thought to use nice to reduce the impact on the service but as the other processes of the server are running for a long time their priority should be lower.
It is unclear to me how a "young" gzip process with a high nice value will compete for the CPU against "old" server processes could someone explain it here.

**Edit:**
The vmstat during gzip operation (server is a cluster, cpu is idle at start because I ran the GZIP test on the failover node to not impact the production).

```
procs     -----------memory----------  ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd     free    buff   cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0  34372 26589240 3160636 2233220    0    0    26    30    5    0  1  2 97  0  0
 1  0  34372 26589108 3160636 2233220    0    0     0     0  388  731  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  34372 26589108 3160636 2233220    0    0     0    30  386  753  0  1 99  0  0
 1  0  34372 26589172 3160636 2233220    0    0     0     0  379  751  0  0 100 0  0
 1  0  34372 26588668 3160636 2233220    0    0     0     0  563  714 18  1 81  0  0  -- gzip starts
 1  0  34372 26588852 3160636 2233220    0    0     0     2  832 1194 25  3 72  0  0
 5  1  34372 26585692 3160656 2233228    0    0     0   656  785 1288 26  4 68  3  0
 2  0  34372 26585296 3160656 2233284    0    0     0     0  829 1390 27  4 70  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588524 3160656 2233292    0    0     0     0  641  860 25  2 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588464 3160656 2233288    0    0     0     0  638  710 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588464 3160656 2233288    0    0     0     2  788 1127 26  3 72  0  0
 2  0  34372 26588464 3160656 2233288    0    0     0     0  627  738 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588488 3160656 2233288    0    0     0     0  629  747 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588568 3160656 2233280    0    0     0    16  600  722 25  1 75  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588584 3160660 2233276    0    0     0    54  636  726 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588484 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  836 1137 26  3 71  0  0
 2  0  34372 26588352 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  618  751 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588180 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  634  781 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588188 3160660 2233272    0    0     0    72  606  750 25  1 75  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588220 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  620  760 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588800 3160660 2233276    0    0     0     0  828 1139 26  3 72  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588676 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  632  737 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588676 3160660 2233272    0    0     0     0  627  732 25  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588716 3160668 2233272    0    0     0    34  606  721 24  1 74  0  0
 1  0  34372 26588716 3160668 2233272    0    0     0     0  636  731 25  1 74  0  0
 0  0  34372 26589184 3160668 2233272    0    0     0     4  679 1162  2  2 96  0  0  -- gzip finish
 1  0  34372 26589308 3160668 2233272    0    0     0     0  371  745  0  1 99  0  0
```

Comment: probably I/O bound...have a look at ionice

Comment: please add to the post the output of `vmstat`

Comment: look at `chrt -i` to schedule a process for idle cpu on linux.

Comment: @meuh thank you. The `man chrt` directed me to `man 2 sched_setscheduler` which is really informative.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro IO are fast compared to the CPU, that is why the gzip can reach near 100% cpu usage

Comment: I am not seeing it more than non-kernel code 27% and kernel code 4%, the id field is idle CPU time.

Comment: you can also use `ionice -c 3` on a process to reduce its i/o priority to when the disc is idle: "The  impact  of  an  idle I/O process on normal system  activity should be zero".

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro 25% is because it is on a quad core which makes 100% of a CPU.

Comment: @meuh  server is able to serve plenty of IOs, that's why I have to deal with a bottleneck at CPU level.